# How do I send a request when I reach the top of the page? in chat in react js

Tags: reactjs, websocket, scroll, chat

I have the chat page and I get page: 1 with websocket

```
 const message = {
            command: 'chats',
            page: 1,
            page_size: 8,
            search: "" // Change this to null if search is default None
        };
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

so when I reach to top the page I need to send page: 2, and page:3

my code this:

```
<Box ref={scrollableRef} sx={{
                            overflowY: "scroll", height: "89%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column-reverse", "::-webkit-scrollbar": { width: "7px", }, "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": { borderRadius: "4px", background: "#24a7588f" }
                        }}>
                            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", gap: "10px", margin: '0 10px' }}>
                                {messages.length > 0 ? messages.map((i, ind) =>
                                    <Message readedMessage={() => readedMessage(i)} key={"i.tetx" + ind} me={!i?.is_dealer_message} role={role} data={i} />
                                ) : null}
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
```

I try with ref `const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = scrollableRef.current;`  but not work currect ,